# Is there a RSA class that supports ISO 9796-2

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I have a requirement to use RSA signatures using ISO 9796-2.

I know about the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in .Net but was not sure if it supported ISO 9796-2.

I know there is a `DSACryptoServiceProvider` but was not sure how that compared to ISO 9796-2.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I don't beleive so, no. However, [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) indicates that it has support for it. "Signer mechanisms: DSA, ECDSA, ECGOST3410, GOST3410, **ISO9796d2**, PSS, RSA."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not read the **ISO 9796-2** standard (and won't pay to read it ;-) but:

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` only support PKCS#1 (1.5) and OAEP padding.

`DSACryptoServiceProvider` only support what's defined in FIPS 186.

Technically you could provide your own padding class in .NET since it's designed to be extensible.

Sadly (i.e. in reality) the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` does not let you do a *real* `EncryptValue` (or `DecryptValue`) so you need another RSA implementation (e.g. use the managed one from Mono).